# Integral sign not displayed properly with JLaTeXMath and FXGraphics2D

Tags: java, user-interface, math, javafx, latex

I am fairly new to both Java and JavaFX, and here on my first bigger project I've encountered an issue. My project is an educational integration game, where the player is supposed to solve integrals on time. My problem is that I cannot get the integrals to display properly. For that, I am using JLatexMath and FXGraphics2D to use the former in JavaFX. However, the integral sign doesn't load properly. Instead, I get this weird "Z" letter:

[JavaFX output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sujEN.png)

I have also tried to substitute the `\int` Latex command with unicode integral sign, however nothing changed and I still got the same output. I also have tried to display `\sum` and something similar has happened, with the only difference being another letter (probably "I" if I remember correctly). Apart from those signs, I think everything is displayed correctly - I've tried to display the quadratic formula and it was all good.

Below is my code responsible for displaying Latex formulas. Also, please note that I have loaded Latex fonts in my main class and as far as I am concerned, they should contain the integral sign.

```
package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;

import org.jfree.fx.FXGraphics2D;
import org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath.TeXFormula;
import org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath.TeXIcon;
import org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath.TeXConstants;
import org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath.Box;

public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        javafx.scene.text.Font.loadFont(
                getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                        "jlatexmath/fonts/base/jlm_cmmi10.ttf"), 1);
        javafx.scene.text.Font.loadFont(
                getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                        "jlatexmath/fonts/maths/jlm_cmsy10.ttf"), 1);
        javafx.scene.text.Font.loadFont(
                getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                        "jlatexmath/fonts/latin/jlm_cmr10.ttf"), 1);

        BorderPane gamePane = new BorderPane();
        Scene gameScene = new Scene(gamePane);
        stage.show();

        stage.setScene(gameScene);
        stage.setMaximized(true);
        stage.setTitle("Integration Bee");

        StackPane integralDisplay = new StackPane();
        gamePane.setCenter(integralDisplay);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(integralDisplay, Pos.CENTER);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        integralDisplay.getChildren().add(canvas);
        StackPane.setAlignment(canvas, Pos.CENTER);
        FXGraphics2D graphics = new FXGraphics2D(canvas.getGraphicsContext2D());
        graphics.scale(20, 20);

        TeXFormula formula = new TeXFormula("\\int_{0}^{2\\pi} x^2 \\, dx");
        TeXIcon icon = formula.createTeXIcon(TeXConstants.STYLE_DISPLAY, 20);
        Box integralBox = icon.getBox();
        canvas.widthProperty().addListener(evt -> drawIntegral(canvas, graphics, integralBox));
        canvas.heightProperty().addListener(evt -> drawIntegral(canvas, graphics, integralBox));
        canvas.widthProperty().bind(integralDisplay.widthProperty());
        canvas.heightProperty().bind(integralDisplay.heightProperty());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    private void drawIntegral(Canvas canvas, FXGraphics2D graphics, Box box) {
        double width = canvas.getWidth();
        double height = canvas.getHeight();
        canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        box.draw(graphics, 1, 5);
    }
}
```

I would be sincerely grateful if anyone could help me with this problem. Please let me know if I should attach anything more. Great thanks and take care!

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: I imagine there is some other font it needs besides the Latex fonts you have loaded, but you'll have to figure out how to debug and find out what font it's trying to use. It's clearly falling back on some font that doesn't have the necessary characters.

Comment: Okay, I've now added minimal reproducible example. Also, I opened the fonts in Windows preview and there was the integral sign, so I believe the fonts are good.